# IOS protocol and framework minimum IOS version check

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos-2, watchconnectivity

I am developing a AppleWatch application. Before I developed an IOS application min version IOS 6.0. AppleWatch application I'm developing with the WatchOS 2.0. Below class code in IOS application class. WatchConnectivity framework and WCSessionDelegate protocol is need min IOS version 9.0. So How do I run the old version without crash

```
.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= __IPHONE_9_0
#import <WatchConnectivity/WatchConnectivity.h>
#endif

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= __IPHONE_9_0
@interface WatchConnectivityManager : NSObject<WCSessionDelegate>{
#else
@interface WatchConnectivityManager : NSObject{
#endif

}

@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL oneTimeSaved;

+(WatchConnectivityManager*)getInstance;

-(void)sharedDefaultsDataSave:(NSString*)params;
@end


.m
#import "WatchConnectivityManager.h"

@implementation WatchConnectivityManager
@synthesize oneTimeSaved;

static WatchConnectivityManager *instance =nil;


- (id) init
{
    /* first initialize the base class */

    /* then initialize the instance variables */
    if (self = [super init]) {
        #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED > __IPHONE_9_0
        if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.0") && NSClassFromString(@"WCSession")!=nil && [WCSession isSupported]) {
            WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
            session.delegate = self;
            [session activateSession];
        }
        #endif

    }
    /* finally return the object */

    return self;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED > __IPHONE_9_0
    // after iPhone OS SDK 9.0
#else
    // before iPhone OS SDK 9.0
#endif
```

You can't use WatchConnectivity framework and WCSessionDelegate protocol before iOS9.0.So do the same thing by using lower APIs or do nothing.

Comment: update my question How you did say. But I cant debug .m file code

Answer (score 0):

Your Base SDK should be iOS 9.0 in order to import framework whereas you can set the deployment target to below 9.0. It will build your project but obviously you need to check the availablity check before calling any method of `WatchConnectivity`.